# Is it possible to virtually dim the brightness of a single window/app?

Tags: macos, bash, mac, applescript

So that apps with dark mode are unaffected but apps without darkmode can be virtually dimmed. I have apps that virtually dim the screen (I think they just apply a dark color filter/tint onto screen), and they work great but they end up dimming the entire screen. It would be useful if this worked on app/window basis so I can virtually dim/darken smaller apps that don't offer darkMode. Is this in anyway be possible, or even through applescripts/bashscripts?

Comment: See if [HazeOver](https://hazeover.com/help.html) can help.

Comment: It looks interesting, but it's more of the inverse of what I'm looking for haha. It's dimming everything except the app your using, whereas what i have in mind is everything else un effected except for a single specified app to be dimmed

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just minimize it?

Comment: but i need to frequently interact with it

Comment: You can likely do it with the powerful [hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon) with [hs.window.highlight](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.highlight.html).

Comment: It looks like there is a pretty solid learning curve for it, but i think it might just manage to do the job and open up the doors to even more possibilities. thanks!

Comment: Good, so I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The poster liked using the powerful
[hammerspoon](https://github.com/Hammerspoon/hammerspoon):

> This is a tool for powerful automation of OS X. At its core,
> Hammerspoon is just a bridge between the operating system and a Lua
> scripting engine.
>
> What gives Hammerspoon its power is a set of extensions that expose
> specific pieces of system functionality, to the user. With these, you
> can write Lua scripts to control many aspects of your OS X
> environment.

The power of hammerspoon comes from its large number of modules.
The module that might be useful here is
[hs.window.highlight](https://www.hammerspoon.org/docs/hs.window.highlight.html):

> This module can be useful to spatially keep track of windows if you
> have large and/or multiple screens, and are therefore likely to have
> several windows visible at any given time. It highlights the currently
> focused window by covering other windows and the desktop with either a
> subtle ("overlay" mode) or opaque ("isolate" mode) overlay;
> additionally it can highlight windows as they're shown or hidden via a
> brief flash, to help determine their location intuitively (to avoid
> having to studiously scan all your screens when, for example, you know
> you triggered a dialog but it didn't show up where you expected it).

This module allows the extensive customization of the highlight overlays
and their behavior, so can most likely be configured to do the task.